# How do I create a wood texture?

Tags: texturing

How do I texture wood so it looks like rough bark? I would like to imitate this texture:

[image: Bark]

Comment: In google find: 1. Blender UV Mapping. 2. Blender Principled BSDF. 3. Free Bark Textures. 4. Blender Displacement Modifier. For the first two and the last one any tutorial from youtube will be good. For the third one maybe you will need to dig a bit to find one with Base/Diffuse/Albedo, Roughness, Normal and Height map. That's it. Any of them steps are also pretty easy to find here on BSE. Even thread with Blender Resources.

Comment: There are a few textures in the image. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LukeD mentioned, you could make your way with what he pointed out. Depending on your skill level, you may succeed or be completely discouraged.

There's a full tutorial from Andrew Price (blender guru) teaching the whole work flow of the steps mentioned in the later comment.
https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/how-to-create-realistic-bread

Yep, it's not for a rough bark but the work flow should help you taking care of some details and difficulties you may encounter during the process.
Replace all the words "Bread" with "Wood" and you'll be good to go!
I guess I saw some wood textures that may help you out on textures.com, it's free for low res.

Good luck!

Comment: This is just a link answer. You didn't do anything else than posting link to a tutorial. This should be posted as a comment.

Comment: Then how can I post a comment for now? Other than my own posts?
You basically blaming me of being unable to shake your hand while they are tied behind my back.

I didn't do anything but trying to help the best I could.  Have a wonderful day.